# Ajax callback breakpoint security issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, debugging

Say I have this code here (somewhat pseudocode)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/user",
    success: function(resp) {
        var data = JSON(resp)
        if (data.user.is_admin)
            // do admin thing
        else 
            // do something else
    }
});
```

Basically the endpoint returns some info about the user and the callback handles the rest. Can I put a breakpoint before the if statement and change data.user.is_admin to be true before the statement is ran? Is that possible?

Comment: Have you uhhhmmm... tried it perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. You can't trust on client code for any security check. Anyone could play with it using something as simple as browser developer tools.

That kind of logic must be on server side, I'm afraid that you have no choice if you need yo keep that safe.